# Insert time in default weather web part

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, spfx, modern-experience, spfx-webparts

By default we have the weather and location web parts in modern SharePoint Online site.

[image: Weather and location web parts]

How can I add the time in the weather web part for a specific location?

Where can I find the source code for the default weather web part?

Thank you!

Comment: Hi @Propool, does below response answers your question?

Comment: @GaneshSanap, Thank you! This is helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot modify the SharePoint online out of the box web parts.

You have to create a new custom web part using SharePoint framework (SPFx) for your requirements.

Check these documentations for more information about SPFx:

1. [Overview of the SharePoint Framework (SPFx)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview)
2. [Build your first SharePoint client-side web part](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-a-hello-world-web-part)

Also, check this GitHub repository where you can find web parts developed by community members. These will help you to get started with: [SPFx web part samples](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples)